# How to check all the characters in for-loop with boolean type?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, boolean-operations

I need to write a function which returns True if and only if the DNA sequence contains no characters other than 'A', 'T', 'C' and 'G')

Here is my code that produces this type of error - 'str' object does not support item assignment

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    i = 0
    for dna[i] in dna:
        if dna[i] in 'ATCG':
            i = i +1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I created another code for the same purpose but it checks only the first character in the sequence and I have no Idea how to make the loop check the following characters as well

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    i = 0
    for char in dna:
        if char in 'ATCG':
            i = i +1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: The problem you're having should point you *exactly* to the issue; think about *when* your function returns. As for the first version, you should have used `while i < len(dna)` as the loop, as you can't assign to `dna[i]`, but the `for` over the characters is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very easy pythonic solution to this problem:

```
def is_valid_sequence(dna):
    return all(c in 'ATCG' for c in dna.upper())
```

This will check every letter, and does not care about the case of the input.

`all()` takes an iterable and only returns `True` if every element is truthy. Since `c in 'ATCG'` returns a boolean, this is a very clean solution.

Comment: thank you! Can you please explain why my first code prompts this error - "'str' object does not support item assignment"?

Comment: The first line of the loop is the problem: `for dna[i] in dna`. On first iteration it evaluates it as `dna[0] = dna[0]`, which you can't do because `dna` is a string and cannot be modified.

Comment: `is_valid_sequence('')` returns `True`

Comment: Yup, and that satisfies the "if and only if the DNA sequence contains no characters other than 'A', 'T', 'C' and 'G'" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has some flaws in looping, in general the loop will run on the characters and the iteration happens for the variable you set in the for loop, the increment of `i` in your second snippet is not being used in your code. Similary instead of `dna[i]` just `for i in dna` would do.

In your case I would suggest something in the terms of sets -

Let's say `dna` is your string with upper cased alphabets

```
permitted_characters = "ATCG"
set(dna).issubset(set(permitted_characters))
```

This will return True and False as per your requirement
set will break down a string into non repeated set of alphabets.